# Matrix Subtraction | ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1,30) (30,455)

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, deep-learning, array-broadcasting

I am performing what seemingly appears to be a legal operation in Linear Algebra but not for Numpy Python.

To give context; I am manually setting up an ANN, performing Backpropagation.

Here, I "Transpose" the `w` (weights) 1D-array (by converting it to a matrix and then transposing).
Below is my trouble-making code:

```
w = w.T
ans = l*dEdW
w = np.subtract(w, ans)
#w = w - l*dEdW
```

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1,30) (30,455)
```

Mathematically:
As long as the no. columns of the first matrix `w` is equal to the no. rows in the second matrix `yield of l*dEdW`, then A-ok.

In terms of Numpy, where am I going wrong?

Note: attempting the below line instead also yields the same error:

```
w -= l*dEdW  # ideally
```

Update:
`print(dEdW)` shows a matrix of `NaNs`. I suspect this to be the issue, as the shape is correct but has no content.

I can only "Accept" one answer it seems. All comments and answers were insightful. I believe this to be a separate issue. Thanks everyone

Comment: You should provide a minimal reproducible example. Here `w`, `dEdW`, and `l` are undefined. At least set them to zero using `np.zeros` for instance.

Comment: @milembar Could I possibly share a simplified notebook with you of this problem?

Comment: That's not really how Stackoverflow works. You need to come up with a problem to solve that could be useful for the whole community, not only you. Thus you need to find a way to reproduce it in a simple way, so that everybody with a similar issue could solve it by reading this thread ideally.

Comment: Ah ok. I've done so now in the Notebook. Will add code to post too

Comment: Looks like you are trying to do some sort of subtraction variant on matrix multiplication, one that pairs columns of one matrix with the rows of the other.  Matrix multiplication does its `sum-of-products` this way.  `numpy` has that - `dot` and `@`.  `APL` and MATLAB provides generalizations on this.  But for `numpy` element-wise operations are the norm.

Comment: It's better if you given an example with simple copy-n-paste arrays, ones like `np.arange(4).reshape(2,2)`.  Give the 2 input arrays, plus a desire result, and clear demonstration of what calculation you expect.

Comment: If this really is a legal operation in Linear Algebra, you should be able to reference some source (e.g. wiki or some LA tutorial).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subtraction like what you are trying to do is not well-defined. Matrix subtraction is element by element, and if you want to subtract those two arrays, numpy needs to have an obvious way to broadcast one of the dimensions into the dimensions of the other array. The following works because numpy assumes you want to repeat arr1, 455 times in the second dimension to match arr2.

```
import numpy as np

arr1 = np.zeros((30, 1))
arr2 = np.zeros((30, 455))

diff = np.subtract(arr1, arr2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm wonder if you just want to subtract `w` from each 'row' of the other array.

```
In [32]: x = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
In [33]: x
Out[33]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
In [34]: w = np.array([10,11,12])
```

Subtracting a (3,) shape from (3,4) produces an error:

```
In [35]: x-w
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-35-c1920b77405b>", line 1, in <module>
    x-w
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,4) (3,)
```

But if we change `w` to (3,1):

```
In [36]: w[:,None]
Out[36]: 
array([[10],
       [11],
       [12]])
In [37]: x-w[:,None]
Out[37]: 
array([[-10,  -9,  -8,  -7],
       [ -7,  -6,  -5,  -4],
       [ -4,  -3,  -2,  -1]])
```

`numpy` has a powerful `broadcasting` mechanism, allowing us to combine arrays with varying shapes - with a couple of well defined rules.